# Nested routes and CRUD operations with additional values for assciation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-api, nested-routes

I created one has_many through relationship in rails api. I also used nested routes.

My models like below;

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comments
 has_many :posts, :through => :comments
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comments
 has_many :authors, :through => :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :author
 belongs_to :post
end
```

my routes like below;

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 namespace :api, defaults: { :format => 'json' } do
  resources :posts do
   resources :comments
  end
  resources :authors
 end
end
```

So here my aims are

> 1. Comments are nested route so that i can create and display comments from post
> 2. Here not any post author. The author is meant for comment owner

I implemented the concepts and working almost all. But i am facing the following 2 problems with associations

1. How to add additional fields for associated table when parent create. Here my requirement is when a post is created, i need to insert one default entry for comment. My post controller implementation for create is like below

> ```
> def create
>   params = create_params.merge(:record_status => 1)
>   @post = Post.new(params)
>   @post.authors << Author.find(1)
>   if @post.save 
>    render :show, status: :created
>   end
>  end
>
>  def show
>   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
>  end
>
> private
> def create_params
>  params.permit(:name, :description, :author_id )
> end
> ```

Here i am passing author_id in the request json. This needs to be added as author id in the comments table. Now i just hard coded as 1. I used '<<' for association entry. This is working but i also need to include two more fields which are :comments and :record_status. Again :comments is from the request itself.

*Note: This is not rails mvc application. This is rails api and input as json.*

2. When i display comments using nested routes i need to show author and also comments from comments table. My comments controller method is ;

> ```
> class Api::CommentsController < ApplicationController
>  before_filter :fetch_post
>
>  def index
>     @authors = @post.authors.where(:record_status => 1, comments: { record_status: 1 })
> end
>
> private
>
> def fetch_post
>  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
> end
>
> end
> ```

Here i got authors but not correct comments in the join table 'comments'

Please help me to solve these issues

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, you want to configure the `posts_controller` to accept the nested attributes for comments. Add this line at the beginning of your controller:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
```

Check the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) for further details on this method.

Then, you need to modify the parameters that the controller will allow:

```
def create_params
 params.permit(:name, :description, :author_id, comments_attributes: [ :author_id, :comments, :record_status ] )
end
```

Modify the attributes listed in the `comments_attributes` array to match those of your `Comment` model.

I'm not sure what you're trying to get in the second problem, but maybe you just need to query a little differently:

```
@comments = Comment.where(post_id: @post.id).includes(:author)
```

The above would return a list of comments including the comment author.

Comment: thanks. I worked out i got it. But a small change. I don't want record_status field value in the request. Instead i need to give as default. How i merge record_status value of associated table in the params.

Comment: You can take it out of the permitted parameters then. Let the client post the value, and the then the server will ignore it b/c it not's a permitted param. Or delete the property before your client posts it to the server.

Comment: I can restrict the parameters from the client. But i need to include that parameters inside my controller. I mean that parameters needs to be given internally not client. Here i need to remove that parameters from the permitted parameters and need to merge in the controller. But merge not worked please help

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. You should either edit this question and show thel code that is not working or post a new question. If this answer has been helpful, it doesn't hurt to up vote it.

Comment: ok i closed this question and created another for my issue to avoid confusions.

Comment: Please see the issue from the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845402/merge-nested-attributes