# Merge Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, rails-api

I have a sample using post, comments and author models. Please see my full requirement from the following thread

[Nested routes and CRUD operations with additional values for assciation in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763795/nested-routes-and-crud-operations-with-additional-values-for-assciation-in-rails)

Here i need to create one comment when a post is created. I used nested attributes and working fine. But my issue is i don't want all attributes from the user. Some attributes needs to be added internally. I can merge if the attributes not having nested attributes. But merge not worked for nested attributes.

I got a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698696/rails-merging-a-nested-attribute-with-strong-params)

Now my params method is like below;

```
private

def create_params
filtered_params = params.require(:post)
                        .permit([:name, 
                                 :description, 
                                 comments_attributes: [:author_id, :comments]])

additional_params = {record_status: 1, comments_attributes: [record_status: 1]}

result = filtered_params.merge(additional_params) do |key, oldval, newval|
  if newval.is_a? Array
   oldval ||= {}
    Hash[oldval.map {|k, v| [k, v.merge(newval.first)]}]
  elsif newval.is_a? Hash
    oldval ||= {}
    oldval.merge newval
  else
    newval
  end
end

result.permit!

end
```

and my create method is ;

```
def create

 @post = Post.new(create_params)

  if @post.save 
   render :show, status: :created
  end
 end
```

But i got error in merge methods like below;

> Started POST "/api/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-06 06:47:08 +0530
>   Processing by Api::PostsController#create as JSON   Parameters:
>   {"post"=>{"name"=>"post 11", "description"=>"desc",
>   "comments_attributes"=>[{"author_id"=>1, "comments"=>"my new
>   .............. Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms
>   (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass):
>
>   app/controllers/api/posts_controller.rb:40:in`block (2 levels) in
>   create_params'   app/controllers/api/posts_controller.rb:40:in `map'
>
>   app/controllers/api/posts_controller.rb:40:in`block in create_params'
>   app/controllers/api/posts_controller.rb:31:in `create_params'
>
>   app/controllers/api/posts_controller.rb:10:in`create'

When i use logger i can understand that error got from the below line. (v is Nil)

```
   oldval ||= {}
    Hash[oldval.map {|k, v| [k, v.merge(newval.first)]}]
```

Please help me to solve this issue